# Spring Boot - @PreAuthorize does not work in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have controller like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public class TestController
{

    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> test ()
    {

        return ResponseEntity.ok("test");
    }

}
```

I tried to write unit test that will test permissions to access this controllers method.

This is my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
 @WebMvcTest(value = TestController.class)
public class AUnitTest
{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private final String url = "/test";

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN")
    public void testAdminUser() throws Exception
    {
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(this.url );
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

}
```

When I remove roles from @WithMockUser and leave empty, by default it will have role USER and then test passes.
When I put roles USER and ADMIN, it will also pass because of USER role.
But whenever I set role to ADMIN it will fail, even though I set that user needs to have ADMIN role to access controller.

I tried with setting username, password, everything from [Spring Security Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test), etc.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Weird. works for me just like you have it except I have `@WebIntegrationTest` instead of `WebMvcTest` and I'm running with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`

Comment: `SpringRunner` is allias for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.  Because `@WebIntegrationTest` is deprecated I tried with `@SpringBootTest`. But then I have problem autowiring `MockMvc`. Then I tried to create mockMvc with `mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();`
but then I get same result.
Because I am writing Unit test, do I need to check for security and leave it for Integration test?

Comment: We also use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecu‌​rity()).build()` and it's working. There must be something outside the test code going on that's preventing this from working for you.

Comment: @Boris When using `@SpringBootTest` you can use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` on the class and then autowire `MockMvc`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to test class.

Or add config sth like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
static class Config {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've searched far and wide and this is the only solution that works! Thank you! If @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) is used directly, it will invoke Spring's permission evaluator. Instead, you need to add the config class which extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration and points to your custom permission evaluator implementation into your test's ContextConfiguration annotation. Otherwise, Spring will deny all requests.

Comment: @bizyb: or just add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` on your test configuration class w/ the custom permission evaluator declared as a `@Bean`. AFAIK, that is the shortest solution.